# Are questions on cuisine of a specific country welcome here?

Tags: discussion, questions

As I'm going to visit a country which is new for me, including its cuisine, I had the idea to ask about local specials, e.g. ingredients I can buy there which are hardly purchasable in other parts of the world.

Another similar question could be about local meals.

Now the first question to ask is whether such questions are welcome on Seasoned Advice.

Answer (score 7):

I would definitely support a question asking about which ingredients (or cooking methods, or equipment, or whatever else) are traditional/unique to a particular world cuisine.

Make sure the cuisine is specific, of course; "Asian" is way too broad and even "Chinese" has far too many variants to answer sensibly.  But if you're asking about, say, Mongolian cuisine, that's probably narrow enough to get something useful out of.

One caveat: Wikipedia has [very extensive articles on cuisines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_cuisines), so for your own benefit, try to phrase your questions so that they're not covering exactly the same ground; I just hate to see people put effort into a question and then get answers which are just copy-and-pasted from Wikipedia.

Also one tip: *Don't* phrase your question like [this one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1235/41). Avoid vague terminology like "authentic".  Ask for something tangible that's not just going to result in a slew of opinions.

As for local meals, that sort of depends on the specific question.  If you're looking for restaurant recommendations then no, that's off topic.  Local *dishes*, eh, kind of sounds like a list of recipes or at best some sort of travel guide, so I'm inclined to say no to that as well.  Maybe steer clear of that sub-topic unless you've got a very specific question that's clearly cooking-related.

Answer (score 0):

Considering local cooking techniques and recipes I would definitely argue that Seasoned advice is the place for a number of considerations.

1. I think it is good to centralize this a bit since the number of users is limited at the moment and I don't think it would be a good idea to make localized versions of the site.
2. No clear line can be drawn to say when a dish is "global" enough to warrant being talked about.
3. Dishes, even if they are not yet widely known can most definitely be of interest to people worldwide.
4. The one disadvantage is that questions about local foods might remain unanswered for a while because of the small number of active users from your region, but that might be a temporary problem and is something the poster needs to take into account.
5. I suspect that stackexchange at some point in the future will end up having sites in different languages, which will kind of naturally solve 4 because people will be inclined to post locally oriented questions in the place where they have the most chance of getting an answer.